# mod_rewrite errors when migrating from Apache 2.4 to Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a list of rewrite rules stored in my website's .htaccess file, rewriting URL's like `http://example.com/cloud/something` to `http://example.com/cloud/index.php?page=something`.

These rules worked perfectly when I was on a server with Apache 2.4.7, however I'm now working on a server with Apache 2.2.22 (not my choice) and for some reason these rules do not work.

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cloud/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+cloud/(?:index\.php|)\?page=([^&]+)/(&|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Whenever I'm trying to access a page with its explicit URL (`index.php?page=something`) it's working, however trying the short way results in a 404 Page Not Found response.

I checked Apache's error.log file and saw that every time I tried to access one of these URL's a new error appeared:

```
[error] [client 10.0.0.90] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/cloud/settings (None could be negotiated)
```

What might be the problem? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to be caused by `MultiViews`. Check your central apache configuration and remove the `MultiViews` directive for this directory and it should work.

Source: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by a symlink in the path being redirected to.